# How to trigger droppable event on dragging element over with jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm making a huge project which should be good regarding performance like every software. But I'm struggling about drag and drop objects.

Let me start with my code. 
Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="drag-me"></div>
<div class="drop-on-me"></div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$('.drag-me').draggable();

$('.drop-on-me').hover(function(){
   let el = $(this);
   el.droppable({
      drop: function(){
         console.log("dropped!");
      }
   });
}, function(){
   let el = $(this);
   el.droppable('destroy');
});
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/GRpOwwK)

I need to trigger droppable event on hovering while dragging objects, because there are so many droppable objects in the page and it consumes much of RAM with the browser and the page crashes.

How can I trigger while I'm hovering with draggable object?

Comment: You would need to use `.trigger()` but there are logical reason why you would NOT want to trigger a `drop` event during a Hover event. It sounds like you want to initialize droppable. You should be able to initialize them and leave them disabled until hover. Or just initialize visible elements as droppable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a level of collision detection. The `drag` event can block out some other events, like `hover` from bubbling up. Consider the following code snippet.

```js
$(function() {

  function getBounds(el) {
    var p = {
      tl: $(el).position()
    };
    p['tr'] = {
      top: p.tl.top,
      left: p.tl.left + $(el).width()
    };
    p['bl'] = {
      top: p.tl.top + $(el).height(),
      left: p.tl.left
    };
    p['br'] = {
      top: p.bl.top,
      left: p.tr.left
    };
    return p;
  }

  function isOver(el, map) {
    var myPos = getBounds(el);
    var tObj = false;
    $.each(map, function(k, v) {
      if (myPos.tl.left > v.tl.left && myPos.tl.left < v.tr.left && myPos.tl.top > v.tl.top && myPos.tl.top < v.bl.top) {
        console.log("Over", k);
        tObj = $(".drop-on-me").eq(k);
      }
    });
    return tObj;
  }

  function makeDrop(el) {
    if (!$(el).hasClass("ui-droppable")) {
      $(el).droppable({
        addClasses: false,
        drop: function() {
          console.log("Item Dropped.");
        },
        out: function() {
          $(this).droppable("destroy");
        }
      });
    }
  }

  var dropPositions = [];

  $(".drop-on-me:visible").each(function(i, el) {
    dropPositions.push(getBounds(el));
  });

  console.log("Mapping complete.", dropPositions);

  $('.drag-me').draggable({
    start: function() {
      console.log("Drag Start.");
    },
    stop: function() {
      console.log("Drag Stop.");
    },
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      var target = isOver(ui.helper, dropPositions);
      if (target) {
        console.log("Make Drop, Index: " + target.index());
        makeDrop(target);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.drag-me {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 300;
}

.drop-on-me {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.drop-on-me.top {
  left: 80px;
  top: 10px;
}

.drop-on-me.mid {
  left: 40px;
  top: 120px;
}

.drop-on-me.bot {
  left: 240px;
  top: 640px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="drag-me"></div>
<div class="drop-on-me top"></div>
<div class="drop-on-me mid"></div>
<div class="drop-on-me bot"></div>
```

Comment: It's the best solution I think. But hard to use it. Because you need to set everything static or relative. But jQuery's position() function may return wrong values if your application has fixed, absolute elements. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: @sundowatch yes and you could use `event` properties for `pageX` and `pageY` if you choose. `.position()` or `.offset()` is a bit easier to call.